# I was trying TinyMCE and wanted to do image uploads, but even the demo at their site doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Tags: file-upload, tinymce

I would like to embed a WYSIWYG editor at my site and was interested in TinyMCE. I created an account, got an API key and some sample code for JavaScript and was looking through their examples page. I'm interested in being able to upload images to posts that users create.

I was looking at the demo at this page - https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/local-upload/ - but the demo doesn't seem to work. Neither upload nor drag and drop seem to take the image I selected.

Any hints on how to proceed? I'd like to see this actually work somewhere before diving in.

Thanks,

doug

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It was working in the regular demos by default. Every time you hit return there was a popup option to upload an image file or a table. Nice. I think I'll give it a try.

doug